# Как спарсить ответ json

Tags: php, api, foreach, instagram

get посылаю так:

```
$request_params = array('access_token' => $access_token);
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?'.$get_params));
```

ответ приходит такой:

```
{
"data": [{
    "username": "kevin",
    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1325536697.jpg",
    "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
    "id": "3"
},
{
    "username": "instagram",
    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_25025320_75sq_1340929272.jpg",
    "full_name": "Instagram",
    "id": "25025320"
}]
}
```

Никак не могу спарсить через foreach, ибо пишет, что объект не существует. Пробовал так:

```
foreach ($result as $key) {
        echo $key->data->username;
}
```

Comment: Итерируйте массив, т. е. `foreach ($result->data as $key) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот полный код

```
 $str = '{
        "data": [{
            "username": "kevin",
            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1325536697.jpg",
            "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
            "id": "3"
        },
        {
            "username": "instagram",
            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_25025320_75sq_1340929272.jpg",
            "full_name": "Instagram",
            "id": "25025320"
        }]
        }';

    $result = json_decode($str);
    foreach($result->data as $key) {
        var_dump($key->username);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно распаковать json в ассоциативный массив, указав вторым параметром функции json_decode значение true. Возможно, вам так будет удобнее.

```
$str = '{
    "data": [{
        "username": "kevin",
        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1325536697.jpg",
        "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
        "username": "instagram",
        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_25025320_75sq_1340929272.jpg",
        "full_name": "Instagram",
        "id": "25025320"
    }]
    }';

$result = json_decode($str, true);
foreach($result['data'] as $key) {
    var_dump($key['username']);
}
```